# how to make custome graph in Android

Tags: android, user-interface

I'm very new in UI design for Android, and I would like to create a custom graph like below image (doesn't matter if not exactly same). Please help me or suggest me some library with beautiful graphs. But highly prefer to knowing how to create own custom.
Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: Check here https://github.com/wasabeef/awesome-android-ui/blob/master/pages/Graph.md

Comment: [link](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiun5v45ZzXAhUBpo8KHY3sA74QFggnMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fdiogobernardino%2FWilliamChart&usg=AOvVaw0nILUTFBgUX6Afm2621sRn)

Comment: Thanks for sugestion guys. any suggestion for creating own custom?

Answer (score 3):

Developing such a module will take too much time and efforts, so here is some libraries that i recommend

```
https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart
https://github.com/lecho/hellocharts-android
https://github.com/wordplat/ikvStockChart
https://github.com/HackPlan/AndroidCharts
https://github.com/ABTSoftware/SciChart.Android.Examples
```

i hope this will help you

Comment: Thanks, i'll check them out :)